# Autocomplete UITextField Sorting Delays

Tags: ios, objective-c, autocomplete

```
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)_substring
{

    NSString* substring = [_substring lowercaseString];
    [successSearchCountryArray removeAllObjects];

    for(NSString *_countryString in countryArray)
    {

        NSString *countryString = [_countryString lowercaseString];

        if ([countryString rangeOfString:substring].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid  country");
        }
        else
        {
            [successSearchCountryArray addObject:_countryString];
        }
    }
 }
```

`countryArray` contain large number of items. it delays my application. i need an alternative way to sort elements from `counrtArray` without delay.

Comment: 1) remove that NSLog 2) Use NSPredicate

Comment: - (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {
 
  // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
  // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
  [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
  for(NSString *curString in pastUrls) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
      [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
  }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}